# using getchar() in c getting Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, getchar

I'm writing a program which requires me to enter a series of char which are loaded into a char array to be used later. The code I am trying to get to work looks like:

```
char temp = getchar();
while(temp != '\n'){//input char into temp until '\n'
    input[strlen(input)] = temp;//adds temp to end of input
    temp = getchar();
}
```

but when I get to this line in the program I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and crashes..
When I replace the \n with another char, for example %

```
char temp = getchar();
while(temp != '%'){//input char into temp until '\n'
    input[strlen(input)] = temp;//adds temp to end of input
    temp = getchar();
}
```

then it works fine, but I want to use the newline and not %. I've looked on several tutorials and they said this is how to input until enter is hit so I'm not sure what the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `input` and how do you initialize it?

Comment: Are you friends with Shlemiel the painter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

while ( (temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n' )

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
input[strlen(input)] = temp;
```

This can easily lead to buffer overflows, because there's no guarantee that the next character is '\0' to signify the end of the string. You need to add boundary checking for the end of input - it only has so much space in it, and you need to make the next character after temp '\0';

Also, as suggested by Tom, you should definitely look into using fgets. (**EDIT:** sorry, I read and typed gets, but I was thinking fgets too)

Comment: The man page for `gets()` strongly advises not to use it. If you have to, use `fgets()` instead.

Here is the official text:
  *BUGS
       Never  use  gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets()  will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security.  Use fgets() instead.*

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `fgets` if all you want to do is read `\n`. [Here's a page on it.](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/gets.html)

You shouldn't use `gets`.